# Dynamic convertion of row data into dynamic columns which are combination of pivoted column and non-pivoted columns using pivot

Tags: sql

I recently started my journey in sql development and stuck with one scenario which is bugging me from many days.

I need to get an output which is based on pivot i hope, but it feels like it is not general implementaion of pivot, as column needs to to be genarated in combination of existing columns and pivoted week column which you can look in below explanation.

I have two tables as per scenario 
table1 : Transaction table which looks like below
[image: TRANSACTIONS (table1)]

table 2 : Calander table
[image: calender table where week and month map for particular year recides in this table]

My output should be like output of my html code (please click on run code snippet )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>SAPID</th>
      <th>MONDAY_3</th>
      <th>TUESDAY_3</th>
      <th>WEDNESDAY_3</th>
      <th>THURSDAY_3</th>
      <th>FRIDAY_3</th>
      <th>SATYURDAY_3</th>
      <th>SUNDAY_3</th>
      <th>MONDAY_4</th>
      <th>TUESDAY_4</th>
      <th>WEDNESDAY_4</th>
      <th>THURSDAY_4</th>
      <th>FRIDAY_4</th>
      <th>SATYURDAY_4</th>
      <th>SUNDAY_4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>63424123</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6882233</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>8</td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried with below sql query

```
select * from (select sap_id,week, 
monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday from 
ssc_transactions)
pivot (sum(week) for week in (select week from ssc_calendar_month_week_map 
where month like 'Feb' and year='2018') )
```

it will so helpfull if i get the required solution in optimized way.

Comment: You tagged this with `mysql`, `oracle` AND `plsql`?  Which ***one*** are you using?

Comment: i am using oracle.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer